# "Let $\chi:\mathfrak h \to \Bbb C$ be a character"?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

I am reading through [a paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9711011.pdf) and I have encountered the following (in section 5)

> Let $H$ be a reductive group ... $\mathfrak h$ be the Lie algebra of $H$, and $\chi:\mathfrak h\to\Bbb C$ be a character. [Let $R_h$ be the infintessimal generator of the right $H$-action on $M$, an $H$-representation; and $\Phi\in\mathcal O(M)$.]
>
> $$R_h\Phi = \chi(h)\cdot\Phi, \qquad h\in\mathfrak h.$$

I don't know how to read this sentence. I assumed that "a character" of a Lie algebra would be a formal character, but I don't know how to interpret a formal character as being a function on the Lie algebra. My best guess after that is it's just supposed to be the trace of the $\mathfrak{gl}_n$-image under some representation, but Google failed to give me any other source that agrees with this guess.

To the best of my knowledge, the author doesn't refer to characters of Lie algebras at any prior point in the paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A character for a Lie algebra is just an element of ${\rm Hom}(\mathfrak{h},K)\cong \mathfrak{h}^*$ by definition. This makes sense, since a group character is also a homomorphism from $G$ to $K^{\times}$.

Comment: I disagree that it makes sense, because not every $G\to K^\times$ is a group character, but I see what you're getting at. But now I am overthinking the analogy: are there other conditions on a functional in $\mathfrak h^*$ for it to be a Lie algebra character?

Comment: This depends on the definition. See for example [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Character_of_a_group). So a group character is just a homomorphism $\chi\colon G\rightarrow K^{\times}$. Perhaps you mean the "character of a representation of a group". Or do you mean [algebraic character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_character) for  Lie algebras?